# Proving that any n equals to 1 after looping even n = n/2 and odd n = n + 1

Tags: algorithm, loops, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that we have an integer n ≥ 1.
Inside a loop, while n is larger that 1. If n is even, then n = n / 2. If n is odd, then n = n + 1. Otherwise, the algorithm would quit the loop and return "success".

How can I go about proving this problem from induction. I want to use induction to assume a k ≥ 1. However, what are the conditions that I cannot assume in the inductive step?

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you really want to use induction, you should look at [strong mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) The standard let it be true for k, show it's true for k+1 won't work here. (Or if it does it will be a pain)

Comment: Hint: after 2 iterations, is the number ever farther from 1 than it started out? Or even the same distance? If so, when?

Answer (score 0):

Split problem in 3 cases.

1) If n = 1, we are finished.

2) If n > 1 and n is even. Than next number will be n / 2, which is definitely smaller than n, if n is larger than 1.

3) If n > 1 and n is odd. Than we can write n = 2 * k + 1. After next iterations we'll get n = 2 * k + 2. After two iterations we'll get n = k + 1. We know that k + 1 < 2 * k + 1.

For case 1) we are finished and for cases 2) and 3) we reduce our problem to smaller problem.

You can workout induction from this.

I can write complete induction if needed.